# Erlang using for() vs lists:foreach

Tags: erlang

The following sample code is from Joe Armstrong's Programming Erlang book:

```
max(N) ->
  Max = erlang:system_info(process_list),
  io:format("Maximum allowed processes:~p~n",[Max]),
  statistics(runtime),
  statistics(wall_clock),
  L = for(1, N, fun() -> spawn(fun() -> wait() end) end),
  {_, Time1} = statistics(runtime),
  {_, Time2} = statistics(wall_clock),
  lists:foreach(fun(Pid) -> Pid ! die end, L),
  U1 = Time1 * 1000 / N,
  U2 = Time2 * 1000 / N,
  io:format("Process spawn time=~p (~p) microseconds~n",
    [U1, U2]).
```

My question is dealing with Erlang fundamentals. It looks like Joe used `for()` to spawn processes, followed by a `lists:foreach` to die them. Is there a reason to use one over the other? Why not use for() again to iterate over the the spawned process list and send them a die message? Is there an efficiency optimization here that I'm missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`lists:foreach` saves you the trouble of determining the length of the list ahead of time, and of specifying it as an argument. The `for` invocation needs to know how long to make the list, so it's necessary. `for()` is usually used as a last resort when there's nothing more appropriate.

Comment: Also, `for/3` does not exist in the language so you would have to implement it yourself. Makes it a moot point.

Answer (score 4):

For the record, another way to express `for` and `foreach` is as list comprehensions:

**for:**

`[spawn(fun() -> wait() end) || _ <- lists:seq(1, N)]`

**foreach:**

`[Pid ! die || Pid <- L]`